# Downloading PDF file from sql database using C# web service in android application

Tags: android, sql, .net

I need help with this issue : i have an android application which should connect to a .NET web service and get a PDF file from SQL database,my question is:

1. what is the datatype of the PDF file should i use to store it in the SQL database?

2.how to get the PDF file using my web service to download it to android application.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

As far as it is not required to actually store the PDF in the database, I would suggest you to only keep a reference to it there.I could assume you are going to use a REST service afterwards, so it would be much more convenient.

Comment: ok until now i'm storing the PDF as binary in the database , and i already using Soap to consume the webservice